# how do I save contents of logcat in a file and change the format of the logcat at the same time?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

```
String fileName = "somefile.txt";
File outputFile = new File(context.getDir("somedirectory", 0), fileName);
Runtime singleton = Runtime.getRuntime();
singleton.exec("logcat -v long"); //set the output format       
singleton.exec("logcat -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath()); //format somehow reset to default here :/
```

This code creates a file and stores the logcat in it but I can't get the format to change to long. I believe it is because the exec functions are two different processes and they need to be one. But I'm not sure how do that.

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted, there is no source that gives the answer, not a duplicate, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it now actually executes two `logcat` commands - the first with `-v` option and the second with `-f` option.
The reason you don't see any output from the first command, is that you don't define where it should go.
You should combine the options together: `singleton.exec("logcat -v long -f myfile");`